# Updater' object has no attribute 'add_handler

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

When entering this code

```
def main() -> None:
    update_queue = queue.Queue()
    bot_token = "token"

    bot = Bot(token=bot_token)
    updater = Updater(
        bot=bot,
        update_queue=update_queue
    )

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('book', book_appointment)],
        states={
            NAME: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & (~filters.COMMAND), book)],
            PHONE: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & (~filters.COMMAND), phone)],
            EMAIL: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & (~filters.COMMAND), email)],
            ISSUE: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & (~filters.COMMAND), issue)],
            TIME: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & (~filters.COMMAND), time)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
    )

    updater.add_handler(conv_handler)
    updater.add_handler(CommandHandler("info", info))

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`
```

an error is issued - Updater' object has no attribute 'add_handler

All necessary libraries were imported correctly: `from telegram import Update, Inline Keyboard Button, InlineKeyboardMarkup from telegram.text import Updater, Command Handler, CallbackContext, CallbackQueryHandler, ConversationHandler, MessageHandler, filters import queue from telegram import Bot`, downloaded the latest version of `python-telegram-bot`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It looks like the `Updater` class simply does not have a `add_handler` attribute.  Why are you trying to access something that does not exist?  Did you write this code yourself, or are you following some online tutorial?

Comment: `Application` and `Dispatcher` objects do have an `add_handler` method.  But not `Updater`.

Comment: Hey. You seem to be using a version >=20.0 of python-telegram-bot but your code is written for version <=13.15. Please either upgrade your code to v20 by reading the [release notes](https://telegra.ph/Release-notes-for-python-telegram-bot-v200a0-05-06) and the [transition guide](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-20.0) or install a version of PTB that is compatible with your code base. Also note that only v20 is officially supported and the library has undergone significant changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_handler` is an attribute of `telegram.Update` (not `telegram.text.Updater`). For v20 of the library please use this [wiki](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki) to familiarize yourself with the new Updater (it is in `telegram.ext.Updater`)

Comment: no, `add_handler` is an attribute of `telegram.ext.Application` from v20